# merge barnch 2 with the latest version of branch 1 in GIT

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch and have created `branch 1` for another functionality.

after sometime i created a `branch 2`. now i realize that i need the changes i made in branch 1 to do some work on `branch 2`.

I have not merge my master with `branch 1`. so how can i get the changes from `branch 1` to `branch 2` leaving `master` branch untouched.

what i can remember is that i have to merge my `branch 1` to `master` first and then create `branch 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to involve `master` in the merge.

You can just `git merge branch1` from inside `branch2`.

Answer (score 4):

```
git checkout branch2
git merge branch1
```